# Do I need to replace the rim?

Tags: wheels, tires

Hit a huge pothole last night and when I checked the driver’s side rear tire when I got home I saw the damage. It does not appear to be cracked thankfully. It really only seems to have flattened at the edge.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

That rim, looks fine and safe, but I would monitor the tire in the same area.

Check for "warts" or bubbles.  The tire sidewall cords may be broken internally, which will not be visible.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like minor cosmetic damage to the rim. If the tire has not popped the bead and is not leaking air all is good. I don't see any damage to the tire itself. This is also good news.

Depending on the speed and direction of the impact there could be hidden issues not readily apparent such as wheel out of balance, tire out of round, shock absorber damage as well as wheel alignment issues. If you notice any odd vibrations or control issues have them checked out by a certified mechanic that you trust.

Comment: Tire damage could be hidden - needs inspecting often...

Comment: I assumed he would be mindful of that possibility of that and would check as a precaution regularly. Internal tire damage over time would affect the tire balance as the internal structures deteriorate probably before it begins to manifest itself on the outside,

Comment: I did continue to drive on it for about about 45 after with the tire pressure display up the entire time. There was no loss of pressure. No visual signs of bubble(s) today. Just for completeness they are run flat tires

Answer (score 0):

I did continue to drive on it for about about 45 after with the tire pressure display up the entire time. There was no loss of pressure. No visual signs of bubble(s) today. Just for completeness they are run flat tires

Comment: If you can drive at highway speeds ( eg 65 MPH) with no vibration it should be good.  I hit an aluminum rim ; I ground and polished the apparent damage . But with a new tire there was vibration at speed , we found a very smooth dent in the rim about a foot long that was not apparent  to the eye.